# How to assign latitude & longitude to a photo "Location" in Photos 6?

Tags: photos, photos.app, geolocation, metadata

I have a specific latitude and longitude that I would like to assign to a photo that does not otherwise have any location information.

eg.  (18.352185, -64.792505) aka 18 deg 22' 26.46" N, 64 deg 45' 37.46" W

When I paste any formatting of these coordinates I can think of into the Photos (version 5.0 and 6.0) info panel "Assign a location",
Apple Maps does some sort of regional search and replace.  In this case, it populates "Caribbean Sea" and a pin hundreds of miles away from the actual coordinates position.

Arrg. this is maddening.
How can I assign a specific location?

[image]

Comment: I'd love one day for someone to come up with the answer 'yes' to this type of question… but as it stands, Maps uses 'postcodes' for locations, not map refs. You can find a map ref, but it won't store it. It has been this way ever since Maps was new.

Comment: I wonder if you could edit the EXIF data with that info and then import the pic? It may still give the incorrect location in photos.app but the correct info would still be in the pic (I assume...)

Comment: Yes I am sure one could properly set the EXIF data on the image *before* import to Photos.  I have many examples where this works correctly with arbitrary lat/long location.    But that is a different problem.  These photos are already imported into Photos app -- too late for that.  (I'm not interested in an export then re-import.  There are other problems with exporting from Photos in good quality *with* edits.)

Comment: it won't be as accurate, and it may be much more irritating, but you can move the pin to where you want it to be...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the location is stored but not displayed.  You can open Photos and click on the photo of interest. Then from the menu bar click on View and about halfway down the menu the is a metadata line. Click on metadata and at the bottom of the displayed list is location. Make sure the location is checked.  Then go to the Window menu and click on info.  The location should be shown.